Cocos creator cannot build when integrating library
I'm making a small mini game project using cocos creator 3.8.1 for web-mobile.
The library I use is zmp, it is used to call the api for the zalo chat application (it is similar to wechat or messenger). The game I made basically ran, but when integrating the node-js library into the game, I encountered a problem.

This is my build config :

I have installed nodejs and installed the library. I have also checked to see that there is a folder for that library in the node_modules folder.
I think the problem is because cocos cannot link to the library I added.
